# Windows Phone 7 - Can not trigger the event from ViewModel.

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm, listbox

I want to write the event for list box from View Model. I try like this:-

```
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Gray" Padding="5" BorderThickness="1">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Border BorderBrush="Wheat" BorderThickness="1">
                                <Image  Name="ListPersonImage" Source="{Binding PersonImage}" Height="100" Width="100" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                            </Border>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" Name="firstName" Width="200" Foreground="White" Margin="10,10,0,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="22"  />

                            <Button DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=listBox1}" Command="{Binding addPerson}" Height="80" Width="80" >
                                <Button.Background>
                                    <ImageBrush  ImageSource="{Binding imagePath,  Converter={StaticResource pathToImageConverter}}" Stretch="Fill" />
                                </Button.Background>
                            </Button>                               
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ItemSelectedCommand,Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

My ViewModel:-

```
  public RelayCommand<MVVMListBoxModel> ItemSelectedCommand { get; private set; }
 public MVVMListBoxViewModel()
        {
           ItemSelectedCommand = new RelayCommand<MVVMListBoxModel>(ItemSelected);
        }

 private void ItemSelected(MVVMListBoxModel myItem)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Name==>" + myItem.FirstName);
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

But nothing happening. Please let me know where I did mistake.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check output window to see if you got binding error. It seems that you got one, because you have `ItemSelectedCommand` defined in `MVVMListBoxViewModel` but `ListBoxItem`'s `DataContext` is corresponding `MVVMListBoxModel`, so binding engine couldn't find the command.

Try to move definition of `ItemSelectedCommand` to `MVVMListBoxModel` and see if message box get displayed this way.

Comment: Hi @har07.. MVVMListBoxModel is class name.

Comment: Yes @har07.. I have tried this solution. But nothing happening. Is there any other way to select the list items from view Model?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the trigger to be upon the `SelectionChanged` of the `Listbox` Item? Then the trigger should be outside the `<ListBox.ItemTemplate> ... </ListBox.ItemTemplate>`.

And the trigger should bind the `CommandParamter` to the `SelectedItem`

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ItemSelectedCommand,Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}"/>
     </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: Hi @bit.. Thanks for reply. I have move the trigger to out side of the **<ListBox.ItemTemplate>**. But I am getting error on click time. **InvalidCastException**

Comment: Bind the SelectedItem to the CommandParameter. updated my answer

Comment: Hi.. Now trigger is working..!! :-).. But the selected item is not showing. It throwing null exception. :-(.

Comment: That's probably because initially no item is selected in the List.
Add a Null check to your code in the ItemSelected method.

Comment: Hi @bit.. I have add like this. **if (myItem.FirstName != null)**  **if (myItem!= null)**. But Not working. **if (myItem.FirstName != null)** This is returning same error.

Comment: I would leave it up to you to figure out what to check for null, the object or the property..

Comment: Sorry bit. I can not figure it out. :-(